# Class throws exception

Tags: java, class, exception

I am trying to refactor a large program in Netbeans and I am a bit lost. I haven't ever been very modular but am trying to correct that now, and for the future by actually learning how to do this. Unfortunately I am having trouble translating some of the tutorials to my beast of a program. SO I was hoping someone here could help. Currently I am trying to break off a chunk of code that takes a file of a specific format and makes a table. I know that I need to make a class and use it to create a table object but I am unsure how. 
I have a main that gets command line input for where a file is located:

```
public class Print {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            // I know this part works
     JSAP jsap = new JSAP();
     FlaggedOption opt3 = new FlaggedOption("cllmap")
            .setRequired(true)
            .setShortFlag('c')
            .setLongFlag("call map");
     opt3.setHelp("Where is the flu, map file? Full path");
     jsap.registerParameter(opt3);
     String cllmp = config.getString("map");
```

I haven't tried to reference any of the new classes I made yet because I have not figured out how to do it correctly yet.
Then I try to send the location of the file to another class so that the other class can read in the file and parse it into a table object.

```
public class Reader extends Print {
 String inpt;

public class FReader {
    //reading in
 //throws exception error
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(cllmp);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    while ((inpt  = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!inpt.equals("Calls")) {
          ...
```

So why does my class FReader throw an exception and how to I make it stop? I can't say `public class FReader throws Exception{` because I then get the error: `'{' expected` same with putting it after `extends Fingerprint2`.
What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

Comment: What exception are you getting (just copy and paste it in) and what does your actual function look like (you've cut off the parameter list and name) and how are you calling it? You've given a bunch of information but left out the most important parts..

Comment: A class *cannot* `throws` anything; only methods can. Also, statements (e.g. `while`) can *only* appear in methods. I suggest starting with a tutorial/book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code must be put in methods, and not directly in the class body. The class is called `Reader`, so it should probably have a `read()` method, and this method should read, and throw an IOException if it can't do it:

```
public class Reader extends FingerPrint2 {
    public String read() throws IOException {
        // PUT YOUR CODE HERE
    }
}
```